# Backbone.js: call a method from another method within a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working in Backbone. Working within a View, I would like to call a method from within another method.

```
events: {
  "click span": "updateURL",
  "click .tag": "clearTag"
},
updateURL: function() { 
   // do stuff
},
clearTag: function(e) {
  console.log(this);
  // this fails
  this.updateURL();
},
```

But `this` in `clearTag` appears to be bound to an element, and `updateURL` is not being called. Is there a way I can call `updateURL` from within `clearTag`?

Comment: Events created through the events structure automatically bind the this context to the view. Are you sure there's not some other code around the call to this.updateURL that's losing the "this" context?

Comment: You're quite right - I was being stupid. Thank you for your help, I'll ask to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Backbone source regarding view event bindings:

```
// Callbacks will be bound to the view, with `this` set properly.
// Uses event delegation for efficiency.
// Omitting the selector binds the event to `this.el`.
// This only works for delegate-able events: not `focus`, `blur`, and
// not `change`, `submit`, and `reset` in Internet Explorer.
```

The context of this should be your view here, so something else is occurring. Could you provide a fiddle with your source?